# How to group_by multiple column, and then split results into a list of data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, split, dplyr

Let's say I have a data frame as follows:

```
A | B | C | D | E
-----------------
* | * | * | * | *
```

I want to split the DF into multiple pieces by unique value of column A and B, and store each piece as an item of the result list (to export to .csv files)

I know that `nest` does pretty much the same thing, but it excludes the columns that I used to nest (meaning A and B is not in the result data frames)

I want to include all columns.

Edit: illustrating photo.
[image]

Comment: Does `split` not do what you want?

Comment: split cannot split by multiple columns. And dplyr is well-known for their speed

Comment: please share example data and expected output.

Comment: See the `f` argument in `split` for how to split by multiple columns.

Comment: I've updated the question. Please review it

Comment: please post the data instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

The result in your image is not computable from the input data as shown, but I'm assuming that's because of copy-paste errors in Excel. What you most likely want is

```
split(data, f = list(data$cat1, data$cat2), drop = TRUE)
```

you can also use `dplyr::group_indices()` as a splitting variable for a (slight) speed gain, at the expense of nice names for your list elements:

```
data('diamonds', package = 'ggplot2')

# base
spl_1 <- split(diamonds,
               f = list(diamonds$cut, diamonds$color, diamonds$clarity),
               sep = '-', drop = TRUE)

# dplyr
spl_2 <- split(diamonds, dplyr::group_indices(diamonds, cut, color, clarity))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  "base" = split(diamonds,
                 f = list(diamonds$cut, diamonds$color, diamonds$clarity),
                 sep = '-', drop = TRUE),
  "dplyr" =  split(diamonds, dplyr::group_indices(diamonds, cut, color, clarity))
)

Unit: milliseconds
  expr     min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
  base 20.0393 21.03635 31.81306 23.96895 25.2412 718.0278   100
 dplyr 14.5076 15.07760 16.54695 15.73990 16.9229  24.3292   100
```

but if you're writing the split dataframes to many CSVs, having nice list element names makes it easier to compose appropriate filenames, for example

```
# don't run this unless you want ~300 CSV's in your working dir!
mapply(function(dat, nm) { 
  write.csv(dat, file.path(getwd(), paste0(nm, '.csv'))) 
            },
  dat = spl_1, nm = names(spl_1))
```

If you split by group indices with dplyr, you'd have to manually add names to the output list with something like

```
names(spl_2) <- sapply(spl_2, function(x) 
  paste0(x$cut[1], '-', x$color[1], '-', x$clarity[1]))
```

before writing to file, which could wipe out any speed gains.